# How can I arbitrarily tell Buildbot to not schedule a build for a given change?

Tags: python, version-control, build-automation, buildbot

At the moment of committing a change to my repository, I want to be able to, in effect, tell Buildbot to not schedule a build for the change.

I know about the `stopChange` privilege in the [authorization logic](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#authorization) but for whatever reason Buildbot never presents me with the button to stop a change, even though I have given myself the privilege. Moreover, even if it worked, I'd essentially have to catch the change in the Web-based UI before Buildbot starts the build. Tricky.

This is how I create my scheduler:

```
c['schedulers'].append(SingleBranchScheduler(
    name="foo",
    change_filter=filter.ChangeFilter(project="foo", branch="master",
                                      repository=url),
    treeStableTimer=300,
    builderNames=["foo-build"]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `fileIsImportant` option to check for the presence of a file among the changes, and if this file is changed, then deem the change unimportant, which causes Buildbot to not schedule a build. So:

```
def fileIsImportant(change):

    if ".skipbuild" in change.files:
        return False

    # There could be more logic here to test other things...
```

Then you register your scheduler like this:

```
c['schedulers'].append(SingleBranchScheduler(
    name="foo",
    change_filter=filter.ChangeFilter(project="foo", branch="master",
                                      repository=url),
    treeStableTimer=300,
    fileIsImportant=fileIsImportant,
    builderNames=["foo-build"]))
```

With the code above, any commit in which there is a change for the file named `.skipbuild` (a file appearing in the root of your repository) won't result in a build being schedule. I use something similar as the code above for my own Buildbot configuration.

Another options would be to check the commit message. Contrarily to what the name suggests `fileIsImportant` is really determining whether a *change* is important rather than just a file. So:

```
def fileIsImportant(change):

    if "[skipbuild]" in change.comments:
        return False

    # There could be more logic here to test other things...
```

With this function, if the commit message has the text `[skipbuild]`, the change won't schedule a build.

I prefer the first option because a) it does not pollute commit messages, b) I find it easier to look for the file to change in my repository root and change it than remember what magic text I need to put in the commit message to skip the build.